# Select column from dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following code

```
library(dplyr)
select_one_col = 'B'
data.frame('A' = 1:3, 'B' = 1:3) %>%
  select(A, select_one_col)
```

I am basically selecting a set of columns where some column names are held in different variable.

Is there any way to correct above code maintaining the basic style?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you could also put select one in two sets of curly brackets (`{{select_one_col}}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [recommended](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html) way to do this currently is:

```r
library(dplyr)

select_one_col = 'B'

data.frame('A' = 1:3, 'B' = 1:3) %>%
  select(A, all_of(select_one_col))
#>   A B
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `base::subset`

```
select_one_col <- 'B'

data.frame(A=1:3, B=1:3) |> subset(select=c('A', select_one_col))
#   A B
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
```

Note, that `'A'`is defined as character in `select=` argument.